# How to map AD Domain Admins group to Ubuntu admins

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, likewise-open

I have installed `likewise-open` and joined the domain succesfully on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I login with a domain user that is a member of `Domain Admins` I don't get administrator priveledges on the Ubuntu box.

I edited the `/etc/sudoers` file and added:

```
%HOME\\Domain^Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

but this didn't work either. I can't run any sudo commands!

**EDIT:**

I've now also tried this (taken from PowerBroker docs):

```
On Ubuntu, you can simply add your domain account to the admin group 
in the /etc/group file by entering a line like the following as 
root:

admin:x:115:LIKEWISEDEMO\kathy
```

but this too didn't work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likewise (or PowerBroker, whatever they're calling it now) lowercases translated group names, in addition for the space character replacement that you've accounted for.  Try:

```
%HOME\\domain^admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Also, is it set to assume default domain?  If so, then you don't want the domain part (I think this behavior started in a fairly recent version, so that might be part of it).  So, also try:

```
%domain^admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

It's safe to just stick both of these in the sudoers file - one or the other should do the trick.

Comment: You know I really thought it would be something so simple, but unfortunately that doesn't work either :(

Comment: I found another site where they said to log in as the user and run the `id` command to see groups user is a member of. `Domain Admins` wasn't listed (added it in AD - sure it was before!), so I logged in as Administrator and it works. That account didn't work before, so your solution must have worked :) THANKS!

Comment: If you do assume default domain = yes. Then %domain^admins ALL=(ALL) ALL is correct.